# query taking too much time with irritated performance

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

1. My query is taking very long time around 1hr
2. it was impacting on DB performance.
3. even for Explain plan also it was taking very long time.
4. please rewrite the query for optimal performance.

Query:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT paid.keyword_id,
               paid.keyword_name,
               stat.orgentrances,
               keyword.rank1,
               keyword.rank_check,
               Sum(paid.clicks)                                     AS sumclick,
               Sum(paid.clicks * paid.avg_position)                 AS
               sumclickavgpos,
               Sum(paid.itemrevenue)                                AS sumitem,
               Sum(paid.cost)                                       AS sumcost,
               Sum(paid.transactions)                               AS sumtrans,
               Sum(paid.impressions)                                AS
               sumimpress,
               IF(Sum(paid.impressions) = 0, 0, Sum(
               paid.impressions * paid.avg_position) / Sum
                                                (paid.impressions)) AS
                      sumimpressavgrank,
               con.item_revenue,
               con.transactions,
               keyword.monthly_search_volume
        FROM   `t_keyword_paid_analytics_google_ib` paid
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT outer_t.keyword_id,
                                 Sum(outer_t.item_revenue) AS item_revenue,
                                 Sum(outer_t.transactions) AS transactions
                          FROM   t_keyword_conversion_ga_ib outer_t
                          WHERE  outer_t.own_domain_id = 720
                                 AND outer_t.traffic_date >= '2012-12-01'
                                 AND outer_t.traffic_date <= '2012-12-31'
                          GROUP  BY outer_t.keyword_id) con
                      ON paid.keyword_id = con.keyword_id
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT outer_t.keyword_id,
                                 Sum(outer_t.entrances) AS orgEntrances
                          FROM   t_keyword_stat_ga_ib outer_t
                          WHERE  outer_t.own_domain_id = 720
                                 AND outer_t.traffic_date >= '2012-12-01'
                                 AND outer_t.traffic_date <= '2012-12-31'
                                 AND ( outer_t.medium = 'organic'
                                        OR outer_t.medium IS NULL )
                          GROUP  BY outer_t.keyword_id) stat
                      ON paid.keyword_id = stat.keyword_id
               LEFT JOIN `t_managed_keyword_ib` keyword
                      ON keyword.id = paid.keyword_id
        WHERE  paid.own_domain_id = 720
               AND paid.traffic_date >= '2012-12-01'
               AND paid.traffic_date <= '2012-12-31'
               AND ( paid.channel IS NULL
                      OR paid.channel = 'Google' )
        GROUP  BY paid.keyword_id
    HAVING paid.keyword_id IS NOT NULL) tempt; 

(outer_t.medium = 'organic' or outer_t.medium is null ) after outer_t.own_domain_id = 720 and (paid.channel is null or paid.channel = 'Google') 
after paid.own_domain_id = 720
```

Tables Structure:

```
mysql> show create table t_keyword_paid_analytics_google_ib\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Table: t_keyword_paid_analytics_google_ib
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t_keyword_paid_analytics_google_ib` (
`keyword_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`target_url_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`own_domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`log_date` date NOT NULL,
`traffic_date` date NOT NULL,
`impressions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`clicks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`entrances` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`match_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1: Phrase, 2: Exact, 3:Broad 4: etc',
`ad_group_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`ad_distribution_network` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`match_query` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`cost` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`cpm` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`ctr` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'percent',
`cpc` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`campaign` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`keyword_status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1: Active,2: Approved, 3: Disapproved, 4: Paused , 5:Pending, 6: Failed, 7:etc',
`ad_group_status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1:ELIGIBLE; 2=PAUSED;3=LOW_SEARCH_VOLUME;4 =LOW_QUALITY_SCORE; 5=DISAPPROVED; 6=AD_GROUP_PAUSED; 7=etc',
`max_cpc` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`quality_score` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`channel` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`first_page_cpc` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`avg_position` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`itemRevenue` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal1value` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal2value` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal3value` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal4value` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`transactions` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal1completions` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal2completions` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal3completions` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal4completions` int(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=BRIGHTHOUSE DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table t_keyword_conversion_ga_ib\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Table: t_keyword_conversion_ga_ib
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t_keyword_conversion_ga_ib` (
`keyword_name` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`own_domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`keyword_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`traffic_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`targeturl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`entrance` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`transactions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`item_revenue` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal1completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal2completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal3completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal4completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal5completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal6completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal7completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal8completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal9completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal10completions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal1Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal2Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal3Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal4Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal5Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal6Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal7Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal8Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal9Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`goal10Value` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`medium` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`source` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=BRIGHTHOUSE DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

please help me here.

Comment: ask specific question here,refer http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your query is supposed to do? At least format it properly if you want someone to help.

Comment: sorry i apologies for my mistake.please help me here.

Comment: your query seems to do a lot of grouping and summing merely to return a single number (`count(*)`). If you just want the count, don't bother doing all of the calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't indicate any indexes.  You will need them to improve performance.

OK, I don't understand the part after the semi-colon, so I'll ignore that.

Your whole query does a count(*) of a sub select, but you are doing a bunch of aggregation in the sub-query (calling SUM) which is work the database doesn't have to do, so eliminate that.

You do aggregation in further sub-queries, so cut that out.

In your main sub-select, where you are just doing a count(*), you select fields that are not in your group by, which is work on the database that is not affecting the count, so get rid of that.

That gives us something like...

```
select count(*)
from (select paid.keyword_id
      from `t_keyword_paid_analytics_google_ib` paid
        left join
          (select outer_t.keyword_id
           from t_keyword_conversion_ga_ib outer_t
           where ...
           group by outer_t.keyword_id  ) con
          on paid.keyword_id = con.keyword_id
        left join
          (select outer_t.keyword_id
           from t_keyword_stat_ga_ib outer_t
           where ...
           group by outer_t.keyword_id) stat on paid.keyword_id = stat.keyword_id
        left join `t_managed_keyword_ib` keyword on keyword.id = paid.keyword_id
     where ...
     group by paid.keyword_id
     having paid.keyword_id is not null
    ) tempt;
```

Also, counts may be faster than selects and you seem to be looking for the keyword_id and counting them in the end.  If you can count as you go that would be better than selecting.  I'm not sure if you can apply that to this query, but keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some index to your tables,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE INDEX cate_id(field_name);
```

here is the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

In your case I would add index to:

```
paid.keyword_id
con.keyword_id
stat.keyword_id
keyword.id
paid.keyword_id
```

because you are making join `on` those fields